# Смена фона div при наведении на ссылку

Tags: css3, jquery, javascript, html5

Как реализовать смену картинки при наведении на ссылку, плавно сверху вниз. По типу ручки у волка из "Ну, погоди!". (при условии что картинки полупрозрачные png) Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На css3 можно [таким образом](http://jsfiddle.net/YMs35/). Если вам не нужно, чтоб верхняя картинка перекрывала нижнюю, то еще проще - надо сделать спрайт и смещать его на нужную позицию. Подключать к этой задаче JS - смысла не вижу... по крайней мере на данном этапе.

Comment: Помогли  спасибо.